# Figure is not appeared in \documentclass[APA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

Tags: wiley-article

what should I do to read a figure in this style?
template could be downloaded here.https://authorservices.wiley.com/asset/Wiley-LATEX-Authoring-Templates_and_Samples_v4.0.zip

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[APA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\articletype{Article Type}%

\received{26 April 2016}
\revised{6 June 2016}
\accepted{6 June 2016}

\raggedbottom   

\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt} % set columns separation <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\title{This is the sample article title\protect\thanks{This is an example for title footnote.}}

\author[1]{Author One*}

\author[2,3]{Author Two}

\author[3]{Author Three}

\authormark{AUTHOR ONE \textsc{et al}}
    
\authormark{AUTHOR ONE \textsc{et al}}
    
\address[1]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\address[2]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\address[3]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\corres{*Corresponding author name, Corresponding address. \email{authorone@Email.com}}

\presentaddress{Present address}

\abstract[Abstract]{This paper describes the use of the \LaTeXe\ \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls}
class file for setting papers for \emph{Mathematical Methods in the Applied Sciences}.}

\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4}

\jnlcitation{\cname{%
        \author{Williams K.},
        \author{B. Hoskins},
        \author{R. Lee},
        \author{G. Masato}, and
        \author{T. Woollings}} (\cyear{2016}),
    \ctitle{A regime analysis of Atlantic winter jet variability applied to evaluate HadGEM3-GC2}, \cjournal{Q.J.R. Meteorol. Soc.}, \cvol{2017;00:1--6}.}
\maketitle

\footnotetext{\textbf{Abbreviations:} ANA, anti-nuclear antibodies; APC, antigen-presenting cells; IRF, interferon regulatory factor}

\begin{multicols}{2} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

Many authors submitting \( \sin \cos \tan \inf_{x} \) to NJD journals use \LaTeXe\ to
prepare their papers. This paper describes the
\textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} class file which can be used to convert
articles produced with other \LaTeXe\ class files into the correct
form for publication in \emph{Wiley NJD Journals}.

The \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} class file preserves much of the standard
\LaTeXe\ interface so that any document which was produced using
the standard \LaTeXe\ \textsf{article} style can easily be
converted to work with the \textsf{WileyNJD-v2} style. However, the
width of text and typesize will vary from that of
\textsf{article.cls}; therefore, \emph{line breaks will change}
and it is likely that displayed mathematics and tabular material
will need re-setting.

In the following sections we describe how to lay out your code to
use \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} to reproduce the typographical look of
\emph{Wiley NJD Journals}.

\section{Sample for next first level head}\label{sec3}

\subsection{Example for another second level head}

malesuada, diam id pretium elementum, eros sem dictum tortor, vel consectetuer odio sem sed wisi.

\paragraph{Fourth level head text}

Some text

\subparagraph{Fifth level head text}

Some text

\end{multicols}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\clearpage

\begin{table*}[ht!]%
    \caption{This is sample table caption 1.\label{tab1}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccD{.}{.}{3}c@{\extracolsep\fill}}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Spanned heading\tnote{1}}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Spanned heading\tnote{2}}} \\\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
        \textbf{col1 head} & \textbf{col2 head}  & \textbf{col3 head}  & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{col4 head}}  & \textbf{col5 head}   \\
        \midrule
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 12.34  & col5 text\tnote{1}   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 1.62  & col5 text\tnote{2}   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 51.809  & col5 text   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}%%[341pt]
        \item Source: Example for table source text.
        \item[1] Example for a first table footnote.
        \item[2] Example for a second table footnote.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table*}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{mmmm.pdf}
\caption{Schematic illustration of the utilized methodology}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Comment: As `WileyNJD-v2` is *not* a well known class (aka does not come with LaTeX), you should also provide information as to where this class can be downloaded.

Comment: it is really famous. It is for wiley journal                                                 https://authorservices.wiley.com/asset/Wiley-LATEX-Authoring-Templates_and_Samples_v4.0.zip

Comment: What kind of figure?